# Overriding highlighted selection in UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I have a custom `UIPickerView` where I use:

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
           viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
         forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
          reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

to fill the picker with `UIView` which has two labels. Is there a way to enable the behavior of highlighting the selected row when touched?

Answer (score 0):

By just adding this at initialization of your picker view.

```
 pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
```